# How do I create a passwordless keychain?

Tags: macos, security, password, keychain

How can I create passwordless keychain on OS X? Specifically, I'm wondering if it's possible to sign application without keychain storing p12 and developer certificates

Using 10.7.1 OS X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the keychain assistant won't let you make a new keychain with no password, you might have to make a new user with no password, and use that keychain for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Hold down Option when clicking OK with a blank password; Keychain Access will allow it.  Just worked for me on El Capitan.  Note-- when you log in (with a password) you will have to press OK to unlock it.

Comment: Guess it's gone on Sierra. :(

Comment: It works on Sierra ! but you have to do it twice and second time it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to remove the password from the keychain. I don't have a password on my keychain. I am also on SL, so maybe Lion is different. I don't know why it would be much different. Try changing the password for the keychain, and instead of entering a new password, leave it blank. That should work.